# How to call materialized views using informatica power center?

Tags: oracle, informatica, sap-data-services

I have script component to refresh 10 materialized views in data services job (BODS) and views created in Oracle but I have to migrate to Informatica job.

How can I create from Informatica Power Center designer?

Please specify the steps as I am new to Informatica.

Comment: 1. You can always call an external procedure. So put all of them into a oracle procedure and call them. Or you can create 1 generic procedure to refresh a MV and then call it in informatica as many time as you can passing multiple arguments. 2. you can also use script to call the MV refresh scripts.

Comment: 1st option is acceptable but have to use only informatica for my requirements. Script component is not available in informatica so how to use ? Any other components available in informatica?

Comment: What do you mean by Script Component? Also, have you tried refreshing the MVs using Pre/Post SQL sections at session level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a PostSQL statement added to a flow that updates the underlying data. 
If you need is a separate process that triggers the refresh, just create a dummy session (with `select 1 from dual where 1=2` as SQL Override) with PostSQL command to refresh the materialized views.

You can make the session a bit more robust by using parameters that will make it possible to adjust the list of views to be refreshed.